# How to loop through storage keys in IndexedDB

Tags: vue.js, localforage

I'm using localForage for IndexedDB and i need to loop through storage keys, but not all. I only need to loop through keys that start with the name "field-".
For example:
field-1, field-2, field-3, ...

Answer (score 0):

From what I found it is not possible to get all available keys in storage. But since you are setting all keys of the localforage at some point, maybe you can store those keys separately.

```
// storing a new key, could be wrapped inside of a function and included anywhere you update localforage
const newKey = "abc"
const availableKeys = localforage.getItem('keys')
  .then((keys = []) => { // localforage will return undefined if the key does not already exists, this will set it do an empty array by default
    // check here if key is already in keys (using Array.find)
    // push the key that you want to add
    keys.push(newKey)
    // now update the new keys array in localforage
    localforage.setItem('keys', keys)
  })
```

doing this you could then use this to iterate all available keys

```
localforage.getItem('keys')
  .then((keys = []) => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
      // you could not check if the key has you pattern
      if (key.indexOf("field-") > -1) // key has "field-", now do something
    })
  })
```

since you do not want to loop over all keys you could again store the subset separately using a filter function

```
localforage.getItem('keys')
  .then((keys = []) => {
    // fiter all keys that match your pattern
    const filteredKeys = keys.filter(key => key.indexOf("field-") > -1)
    // store filtered keys in localeforage
    localforage.setItem("filteredKeys", filteredKeys)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
localforage.iterate(function(value, key, iterationNumber) {
  if (key.indexOf("field-") > -1) {
    // do something
  }
});
```